# how to create a migration that will populate my menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create a migration to populate menu. For example I have relationship
survey has_many :question and question belongs to Survey
Question has_many :answers, and answer belongs to question

This is relationship I have and I have data driven menu where menu is Survey and under survey there are questions. so menu would be like this

```
Survey1
  *question1
  *question2
Survey2
   *question1
   *question2
```

any ideas??

Comment: If you don't have a Menu model then you can't make a menu migration.

Comment: No I dont want a menu migration. I want a migration that will populate a menu with the survey and questions. Right now I have working menu but with rough data.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this, so...

Step 1. Use acts_as_tree to create a tree-structured menu.

Step 2. Create that tree structure in seeds.rb so you can do rake db:seed

```
about_us    = root.children.create(:title => 'ABOUT US') {|r| r.url = '/pages/about_us'}

about_us.children.create(:title => 'biography')
about_us.children.create(:title => 'our clients')
about_us.children.create(:title => 'office locations')
about_us.children.create(:title => 'contact us')
```

Step 3. Create a helper in application_helper.rb (or wherever) to build the menu out in html.